# Jquery | Open all links of subfolder in new tab

Tags: jquery, subdirectory

I need to open all urls of a Wordpress subfolder called documents in a new tab. For example   "http://www.example.com/documents/*"

Scenario: When displaying a post grid of all posts in the directory "documents", each post would open in a new tab.

I've tried editing external link scripts to make this work for me, but I'm not getting anywhere. I"ll need to do this with JQuery /Javascript or even a WP function.

Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) in order to attach an event handler for all anchors containing the *documents* folder.
And using window.open(url, '_blank') you will open the link in a new tab:

```js
// using jQuery
$('a[href*="documents/"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    win.focus();
})

// using javaScript
 document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="documents/"]').forEach(function(ele, inex) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var e = event || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        var win = window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Unfortunately, it isn't working for me. It's probably something I'm doing wrong. I enqueued  it via the functions file.
Could it make a difference that the links are generated via Visual Composer post grid element? I'm linking to posts within the post-type "documents" which is where I got the url http://www.example.com/documents/

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? Did you wrap the code in the jQuery ready function?

Comment: If the anchors are generated dynamically you need to delegate the event handler. $(document).on('click', 'a[href*="documents/"]', function(e) {

Comment: calling <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> in the header-single file

and in the functions.php file:

 //Attempt to force links to document posts to open in a new tab
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'footer_so_18774457' );
function footer_so_18774457()
{
  if( !is_single() )
        return;
   echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('a[href*='documents/']').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    win.focus();
})

});
    </script>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gaetanoM for figuring this out for me!

For those with a similar problem, the final working solution was:

```
    // Open all document post types in a new tab
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href*="documents/"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    win.focus();
    })

    });
```